# SSO experience between token based and cookie based application

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-account

Currently I have two applications with **broken** sso experience. Below is scenario :

**Application 1** is Single Page Application, that uses Azure AD as an authorization end point and OAuth 2.0 implicit authorization grant to secure its web API back end (in short I refer this as Azure AD token base authentication) Almost similar to below flow :

[image]

**Application 2** is a web application that uses OpenIDConnectAuthentication middleware in tandem with CookieAuthenticationMiddleWare and uses same Azure AD as authorization end point(in short I refer this as Azure AD cookie based authentication) Almost similar to below flow :

[image]

**Is this broken SSO experience between application with token base authentication and application with cookie base authentication is expected ?**

I accept I could have debugged and checked why and what before posting, but just wanted to see if its known issue before I go ahead with local code set up and all.

Comment: You should SSO in that both apps have an active AAD cookie set in the user's browser for the `login.microsoftonline.com` domain. Can you elaborate on the experience right now and how it's different than what you're expecting?

Comment: @DanielDobalian Thx !! basically when I go to other app, it simply prompts me to enter username and pwd again. as part of sso, I am expecting silent seamless authetication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the best Azure Sample for achieving the experience you are looking for: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

You should not be prompted to enter the username and password a second time. At most you may have to click a second time to sign in but even that can be configured within the code. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MohaxN6fsDs) my colleague and I made demonstrating how to set up this experience with two web apps using the Azure sample. Based on your description, this seems to be what you are looking to achieve.